# Hibernate not using sequence defined in Liquibase

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

I have defined a sequence in my `liquibase` changelog, but looks like `Hibernate` is ignoring it when inserting the entities.

Sequence defined in Liquibase looks like this.

```
<createSequence cycle="false" incrementBy="1"
            startValue="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="1"
            sequenceName="seq_vehicle" />
```

And in the Entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "VEHICLE_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "VEHICLE_SEQ", sequenceName = "SEQ_VEHICLE")
    private Long id;
```

I also added this property to `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
```

The problem is that whenever new entity is inserted to the DB, it just ignores Liquibase sequence, and starts from 50 and increments by 50 for any new insert. How do I fix that?

Comment: Try to put in lowercase the sequence name: `sequenceName = "seq_vehicle"` on `@SequenceGenerator`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `allocationSize = 1`:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "VEHICLE_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "VEHICLE_SEQ", sequenceName = "SEQ_VEHICLE", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
```

As @veljkost explained, the default value for the `allocationSize` [is 50](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#allocationSize()).

Answer (score 0):

Use `@GenericGenerator` instead of `@SequenceGenerator`.

```
@Id
@Column
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "VEHICLE_SEQ", 
    strategy = "sequence", 
    parameters = {
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "SEQ_VEHICLE")
    }
)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "VEHICLE_SEQ")
private Long id;
```

The `@SequenceGenerator` in your case hibernate's HILO mechanism which, by default, uses default allocation size of 50, and that's why you see gaps in id values id the database.